# How to read Oracle BLOBs in R using library(odbc)

Tags: r, oracle, odbc, blob

I'm trying to read some binary data from Oracle BLOBs into R, but the query results appear incomplete. For example, a given record might have a BLOB of length 15,203 come back as only 867 bytes. Each of these BLOB fragments look to match the last few bytes of the actual BLOB in Oracle. So for example the BLOB coming back as 867 bytes does match the final 867 bytes of the 15,203 byte BLOB. The other clue is the BLOB fragment is always the length of the actual BLOB mod 2048. It's as if each BLOB fragment is just the last piece of something that was broken up in chunks of 2048 bytes.

Is there something different that has to be done to read BLOBs other than the usual dbConnect, etc.?

This is Oracle 19 from R running in Linux using library(odbc), drivername "RStudio Oracle ODBC Driver", driver.version "1.4.8.1008".

```
# connect to the Oracle server
myConn<-odbc::dbConnect(
 odbc::odbc(),
 Driver = "Oracle",
 ...etc...
)

# query the server for blobs (column b) and to get the actual length of each blob
qBlobs<-odbc::dbSendQuery(myConn, "select b, dbms_lob.getLength(b) as b_len from ...etc...")
x<-odbc::dbFetch(qBlobs)
odbc::dbClearResult(qBlobs)

# row 1 blob should have been 15,203 bytes per dbms_lob.getLength(b)
x[1,2]
15203

# row 1 blob came back as only 867 bytes per R
x[1,1]
<blob[1]>
[1] blob[867 B]
```

I can query just fine from another client, it's only in R that I'm seeing these BLOB fragments come back.